# How to use $index on ng-click within ng-repeat-start/end

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-show, ng-hide

I have a simple ng-repeat-start and ng-repeat-end. Within the ng-repeat, i have an ng-click. How can i use the $index from the ng-repeat-start within the ng-click to show/hide an ng-show.

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="data in MyData track by $index">
        <p>Show me my {{ data }}</p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div>
            <p>Select</p>
            <span ng-click="{{'showHidden'+$index = !'showHidden'+$index}}"></span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <p ng-show="{{'showHidden'+$index}}">My hidden content, my hidden content, my hidden content, my hidden content, my hidden content, my hidden content </p>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li ng-repeat-end>
        <p>{{ data.name }}</p>
        <p>{{ data.age}}</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Essentially what i have is:

```
ng-click="{{'showHidden'+$index = !'showHidden'+$index}}"

ng-show="{{'showHidden'+$index}}"
```

Where $index is determined from the parent ng-repeat-start

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize a temporary variable to track the visibility boolean (i just called it 'visible'). Each loop of an ng-repeat has its own $scope, so the new variable is constrained to that $scope.

http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/12783/

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat-start="data in MyData track by $index" ng-init="visible = false">
        <p>Show me my {{ data }}</p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div>
            <p>Select</p>
            <a href="" ng-click="visible = !visible">*</a>
        </div>
        <div>
            <p ng-show="visible">My hidden content, my hidden content, my hidden content, my hidden content, my hidden content, my hidden content </p>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li ng-repeat-end>
        <p>{{ data.name }}</p>
        <p>{{ data.age}}</p>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```